# How to scroll and stay where specific element is there?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is **my code**:

```js
$('html, body').stop().animate({scrollTop:$('.select').offset().top-80}, '100');
```

```css
div{
border: 2px solid gray;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div> div1 </div>

<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>

<div> div2 </div>

<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>

<div class='select'> div3 </div>

<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>

<div> div4 </div>

<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>

<div> div5 </div>
```

And it works correctly. My question is just about **jumping**. When page loads, first it goes (jumps) to the top of page and then scrolls to that specific position. How to prevent it? I want don't go up and then go down, I want if current scroll is on that specific position then nothing happens. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the document (page) is rendered, by default it would always put the focus on the top of the page and unfortunately css doesn't provide any trick alone to set it to get over it.

The best you can do is to use `setTimeout` function around it and delay the transition to make it look more linear.

```
setTimeout(function(){
$('html, body').stop().animate({scrollTop:$('.select').offset().top-80}, 3000); },2000);
```

Here's an example : http://jsfiddle.net/86829ryz/18/

Comment: Yes, using a delay makes it more better. anyway thanks +1:-)

Answer (score 1):

I think you're asking to jump to a specific `<div>` on page load... if that's the case, the easiest solution would be to use a specific ID for the target `<div>`, then append that `<div>`'s ID to the end of the URL that you're using to link to the file.

So, for example, if you had `<div id='select'>`, then you could link to that div directly without the scroll effect by using `http://yourwebsite.com#select`.

Other jumps can be made directly to other IDs using the `href` attribute in anchor tags (e.g. `<a href='#select'>`). If you wanted to keep the scrolling effect for those kinds of jumps (rather than scrolling automatically on page load like you're doing here), you would need to attach an event listener to anchor tags using JavaScript or jQuery.

Comment: Yes I know how should I work with anchor in the URL. Anyway +1 for your answer.